# CookieContainer の仕様について

Tags: c#, .net

CookieContainerへCookieを追加する際、セパレーター(セミコロンやカンマ)のエスケープはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

代替案としてパーセントエンコーディングする方法や、スペースに置き換える方法が見つかりましたが、本来の仕様としてセパレーターを値に設定する方法が知りたいので質問させていただきました。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

あくまで`System.Net.Cookie`クラスの仕様としてですが、`new Cookie("name", "\"abc,def\"")`のように値の両端に二重引用符を追加すれば制御文字を含めることが出来ます。

これはHTTPの仕様としては[RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965)に規定されている動作ですが、より新しい[RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1)では引用しても制御文字を含めることはできません。ですので結局どのようにエスケープされるのかは対象サーバーの挙動を確認する必要があると思います。